# PKCS11 - Delete prefix "SunPKCS11-"?

Tags: java, sign, pkcs#11, gemalto

It is possible to delete the prefix "SunPKCS11-"?
because always I get a provider whose name is "SunPKCS11-SmartCard" and not "SmartCard" .

this my code :

```
String configName = "pkcs11.cfg";

Provider p = getInstalledProvider(providerName);
if (p == null)
{ 
    p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
}

Security.addProvider(p);
return KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", p, loadProtection);
```

and this my configuration file :

```
name = SmartCard
description = configuration file
library =C:\Program Files\Gemalto\Classic Client\BIN\gclib.dll
```

Comment: I can get a provider name "SmartCard". unfortunately, I noticed that the provider I created has the name "SunPKCS11-SmartCard". My question: How to remove "SunPKCS11-"?

Comment: No, because the name of the provider is 'SunPKCS11-SmartCard', not 'SmartCard'. What do you care what the name of the provider is? Prior comment of mine to this effect mysteriously removed, reasons unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EJP pointed, you cannot change the provider name. When you are creating the provider instance, Java prepends the string `SunPKCS11-`prefix to the name you provide. You can look at the Java documentation about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config).

Once you have created your provider instance, it is recommended to get the name using the [Provider.getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html#getName--).